# Webcast sábado 15 diciembre 2018

Tags: discusión, webcast

Con el buen Gonzalo Bianchi ([@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi)) haremos un webcast en vivo este sábado 15 de diciembre vía YouTube. Hablaremos durante 1 hora aproximadamente sobre los fundamentos y habilidades en el C:\erebro que todo buen desarrollador de software debe tener by default.

Links:

http://fredyfx.com/1115

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqzVCY1jzXQ

Los esperamos :D

PD: Espero que este tipo de publicaciones sean aceptadas y en caso tengan que darle de baja, entenderé, todo sea para mantener el orden del sitio :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al menos a mi me parece bien y con gusto estaré a la espera del evento, saludos a los dos

Comment: eeepaaa!! venga vamos, el chat estará habilitado :D

Comment: luego me invitas a mi a uno @fredyfx

Comment: ¡Dale y hablamos de programación Web con entorno LAMP y DotNetCore en Apache!

Comment: [Lo he añadido al chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ISc.png) como evento para que a nadie se le olvide :P y tambien [sale en el sitio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEgJY.png) (ups me comí una *"f"*, perdoname @fredyfx)

Comment: seria genial si expliquen el CORS que es un error tipico , solo una breve explicacion! ya qye hablan de programacion Web

Comment: eeepaaa!!! gracias @lois6b!!! descuida, es un clásico confundir y/o abreviar letras, la gran intención cuenta :D

Comment: wowowowwo , esto se pone bélico, estaré ahí para ver que tal. Saludos.

Comment: El afiche tuvo su evolución gracias a un amigo del trabajo, el diseño salió épico en comparación a lo que había :D

Comment: El link de la derecha (PRÓXIMOS EVENTOS) aparece dos veces y lleva al chat y no a esta pregunta.

Comment: @ArtEze y del enlace del chat nos lleva a este post :D

Comment: @ArtEze si, los eventos son cosa del chat. entonces al crearlo te lleva a la sala de chat relacionada. por eso puse además un pin a este post ^^ Creé dos sin querer y  borré uno... no se por qué en meta salen dos. en SOes sale un anuncio solo.

Comment: @fredyfx no conozco de dichas tecnologías, pero puedo participar y aportar de otros temas

Comment: @shadow "Linux Apache Mysql PHP", vi las etiquetas que normalmente respondes :D